# Delphi - Where is the IDE picking the list of form names from?

Tags: delphi, ide

Especially to populate the "inheritable items" and "forms creation" dialogs

I am asking because since a few days, I cannot create inheritable items
anymore as there is a space (or a tab?) appended to each form name so I
end up with an error message when inheriting like 'basewindow 2 is not a
valid identifier' (notice the space between basewindow and 2)

This is very blocking for me as all the forms in the project are inherited from a common ancestor ...

Note: on the newly created froms, there are no space and they work fine. It is a plan d2010 setup, no extra IDE tools or utilities loaded;
Note 2: this relates to one project only

Any idea ?

thanks in advance
Didier

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have done some investigation into this in relation to the question: [Register custom form so I can inherit from it from multiple projects, without copying the form to the Object Repository folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733216/register-custom-form-so-i-can-inherit-from-it-from-multiple-projects-without-cop). Although it isn't in my answer there, I have since concluded that the IDE will only let you inherit from items explicitely added to the project.

I would therefore say that it picks up those inheritable items from the dpr file. A line like

```
  UnitOKFrame in 'UnitOKFrame.pas' {OKFrame: TFrame},
```

would add an OKFrame to the inheritable items list.

So my "guess" is that somehow you have gotten extra spaces between the name of your forms/frames and the colon that separates it from its type. Something like:

```
  UnitOKFrame in 'UnitOKFrame.pas' {OKFrame : TFrame},
```

If that is indeed the case, I would file a QC report with Embarcadero. They could bother to make the parsing of the dpr a bit more robust and friendly to us poor programmers :-)...

---

As Uwe mentioned in the comments, forms are included without a type identifier:

```
  UnitLogonForm in 'UnitLogonForm.pas' {LogonForm},
```

in this case you might have extra spaces between the curly braces surrounding the actual name:

```
  UnitLogonForm in 'UnitLogonForm.pas' {LogonForm },
```

Comment: In case of a form the colon and classname is omitted.

Comment: @Uwe: thanks hadn't noticed that. Will amend my answer to include it.

Comment: IIRC using the builtin code formatter on a *.dpr breaks the pas-dfm correlation by inserting extra spaces.

Comment: +1, for most practical purposes this is (unfortunately) where the IDE gets it's list from. Theoretically you can also write an Expert to add new items to the "New" gallery".

Comment: Marjan, you are absolutely spot on; and I know how I did that: I reformated (ctrl+D) by accident instead of saving (CTRL+S) the dpr!!! After that I had several misbehavior : could not inherit windows, when opening the project the mainform would not open, sometimes forms would not be found in the project etc ... I'll file a QC

Comment: Just today had this issue. Found out that if the comment that is placed just before the class implementation in the **unit** is also wrong (the one that looks like `{ TForm1 }`) that form also fails to appear in the *inheritable items* list.