# Delphi: How to get rid of "Ancestor of TMyForm not found error'?

Tags: delphi, ide

I have some forms inherited from a `TMyForm` (`TMyForm` is a 3rdparty component with source code form).

When I open in the IDE my forms inherited from TMyForm I have:

> Error creating form: Ancestor for
>   'TMyForm ' not found.

The workaround is to open the `TMyForm` unit in the IDE and then try top open my inherited forms.

But how can I avoid that Delphi gives this error and is able to open my forms even if `TMyForm` is not opened in the IDE?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to have the parent form opened in the IDE or added to the project, there's no workaround, unfortunately. Over here: [Register custom form so I can inherit from it from multiple projects, without copying the form to the Object Repository folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733216/register-custom-form-so-i-can-inherit-from-it-from-multiple-projects-without-cop) I attempted lots and lots of things, without success.

Comment: In my case I have a single project, so i added to dpr and it worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: You could write an IDE expert that watches as files are being opened and on the right files open the parent form first. I've used this and it works.

Answer (score 3):

My Workaround. There are several ways:

- Add to project full path to all of the parent form. Uncomfortable, because of absolute path
- Add package with parent forms to the project list. In this case, no problems there. But every time it is necessary to open a components
  in the delphi environment.
- Use a temporary solution from embarcadero.

There is automatically opens all the child forms:

Ticket, was created about 10 years ago: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=8376

Here you can download the version for Delphi XE2: https://bitbucket.org/hemn/autoopenunit

I recommend it!

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).

Comment: Sorry, but that ScanFF change seems off for me. Why on Earth undo Unicode? I made more extensive optimization https://github.com/the-Arioch/XE2_AutoOpenUnit - and hit XE2 string double-free bug yet again...

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching all over for a solution to this and it seems I've finally found one.

I'm using a package with several base forms and frames.

I've added these to the repository, yet still the error came up.

Some of the forms and frames didn't show a 'dfm' in the Project Manager, it seems key to this, is to edit the .dpr file and add the name in curly brackets:

```
fIBSConnectionForm in 'GUI\BaseGUI\fIBSConnectionFrom.pas',
```

into

```
fIBSConnectionForm in 'GUI\BaseGUI\fIBSConnectionFrom.pas' {frmIBSConnectionForm},
```

and for frames, make sure to use {f...: TFrame}

After doing this and restarting Delphi, I could open descendant forms again!

Comment: for me full path in DPR files lead to some unwanted side effects (do not remember exactly what), and specifying form name without path lead to another error - `Can not open c:\windows\system32\frmIBSConnectionForm` - crazy...

Comment: It's not the full path, it's the relative path to the project file. And obviously, in my case it's TfrmIBSConnectionForm (without the 'T', this is dropped) and unit fIBSConnectionForm - your form probably has a different name.

Comment: Sure, I changed from name to match your example. In my case XE2 just tries into system32. Crazy IDE, just crazy. It even barks at forms derived directly from `TForm` !!!